# How to convert Char field to datetime field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, connection-string

I have datetime stored in a table as Char(30) and i want to convert them into mysql standred datetime format.

so I tried this

```
   SELECT STR_TO_DATE(next_attempt, '%Y-%m-%d %T') as date FROM Table LIMIT 10;
```

This is returning Null always!
This is the current format (5/16/2011 20:14)   so in my char(30) field i have (5/16/2011 20:14) and I want to convert it to (2011-05-16 20:14:00)

What I doing wrong for it to keep returning Null?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try replace "/" for "," and use '%m,%d,%Y %T'

```
STR_TO_DATE(replace('5/16/2011 20:14','/',','),'%m,%d,%Y %T')
```

here works fine:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(replace('5/16/2011 20:14','/',','),'%m,%d,%Y %T') as date from dual
```

Comment: now it worked. I have no idea why it did not work for when when i did the replace! Any way thank you so much :)

Comment: yours char are padronized? always are 'month/day/year time', because i execute the slq for me and it work...